# Concept checking of static member variables compile error on gcc

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to apply the technique described in http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/227500449

With the sample code below, I expect the output:

> 1 0 0 0
>   0 1 0 0
>   0 0 1 0
>   0 0 0 1

And this is indeed what happens if I compile using clang. But with gcc, this code gives the following errors:

```
junk.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const bool has_foo_member_variable<B>::value’:
junk.cpp:45:5:   instantiated from ‘void print() [with T = B]’
junk.cpp:82:14:   instantiated from here
junk.cpp:30:75: error: ‘B::foo’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int B::*’
junk.cpp:30:75: error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form `&X::Y'
junk.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const bool has_foo_member_variable<D>::value’:
junk.cpp:45:5:   instantiated from ‘void print() [with T = D]’
junk.cpp:84:14:   instantiated from here
junk.cpp:30:75: error: ‘& D::foo’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int D::*’
junk.cpp:30:75: error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form `&X::Y'
```

I am using gcc 4.5.1... I looks like gcc is not following the correct SFINAE rules, but I am not 100% sure. Is clang correct and this is a gcc bug?

```
#include <iostream>

struct small_type { char dummy; };
struct large_type { char dummy[2]; };

template<class T>
struct has_foo_member_function
{
    template<int (T::*)()> struct tester;
    template<class U> static small_type has_foo(tester<&U::foo> *);
    template<class U> static large_type has_foo(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(has_foo<T>(0)) == sizeof(small_type));
};

template<class T>
struct has_foo_static_member_function
{
    template<int (*)()> struct tester;
    template<class U> static small_type has_foo(tester<&U::foo> *);
    template<class U> static large_type has_foo(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(has_foo<T>(0)) == sizeof(small_type));
};

template<class T>
struct has_foo_member_variable
{
    template<int T::*> struct tester;
    template<class U> static small_type has_foo(tester<&U::foo> *);
    template<class U> static large_type has_foo(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(has_foo<T>(0)) == sizeof(small_type));
};

template<class T>
struct has_foo_static_member_variable
{
    template<int *> struct tester;
    template<class U> static small_type has_foo(tester<&U::foo> *);
    template<class U> static large_type has_foo(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(has_foo<T>(0)) == sizeof(small_type));
};

template<class T>
void print()
{
    std::cout << has_foo_member_function<T>::value << " "
        << has_foo_static_member_function<T>::value << " "
        << has_foo_member_variable<T>::value << " "
        << has_foo_static_member_variable<T>::value << "\n";
}

struct A
{
    int foo()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct B
{
    static int foo()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct C
{
    int foo;
};

struct D
{
    static int foo;
};

int main()
{
    print<A>();
    print<B>();
    print<C>();
    print<D>();
}
```

Comment: I can't confirm whether this is correct C++ or not.  But I can confirm one more compiler in it's favor if majority counts for anything.  Visual C++ has no problem with it, and output is exactly as you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is **correct**.

> Is clang correct and this is a gcc bug?

Yes most probably. [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) confirms that your code is correct.